# constructing Pydantic schema for response modal fastapi

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

i have a response of data like this

```
{
  "k9KNg_id": {
    "card_name": "item1",
    "price_updated_date": "2022-04-07T19:30:25.78Z",
    "card_img_id": "https://testingimg",
    "set_name": "some testing set",
    "set_tag": "mm3",
    "rarity": "rare",
    "price_normal": 32.99,
    "price_foil": 54.99
  },
  "EWrZ5_id": {
    "item_name": "item2",
    "price_updated_date": "2022-04-07T08:05:52.385Z",
    "item_name_img_id": "https://testingimg",
    "set_name": "testing set",
    "set_tag": "exp",
    "rarity": "super rare",
    "price_normal": null,
    "price_foil": 379.99
  },
```

so now i am trying to write this api return with fastapi with a basemodel schema. how should i write the schema? since i have my item id and then my item product details.

```
 item_dict.update({
            "item_name": abc["item"]["name"],
            "price_updated_date": ed["prices"]["lastUpdatedAtUtc"],
            "item_img_id": item_img_url,
            "set_name": ed["name"],
            "set_tag": ed["abbreviation"],
            "rarity": ed["rarity"],
            "price_normal": normal_price,
            "price_foil": foil_price
        })
        data_return[ed["card_id"]] = ckd_dict
    return data_return
```

and on my api call i just send a very simple fastapi call

```
@router.get("/{item_name}")
async def search(item_name):
    item = get_item(item_url, item_url_type, item_name)
    return item
```

i wanted to create a response_model for my fastapi to return the data but i am not sure how to construct my schema with this kind of data structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by separating the list (dictionary) response and the card structure:

```
class Card(BaseModel):
    card_name: str
    price_updated_date: datetime.datetime,
    card_img_id: str
    set_name: str
    set_tag: str
    rarity: str
    price_normal: float  # or maybe better, decimal.Decimal  - depends on your use case.
    price_foil: float  # same
```

You can then use this in your `search` decorator directly and say that you return a dictionary of cards:

```
@router.get("/{item_name}", response_model=Dict[str, Card])
async def search(item_name):
    pass
```

However, you should be able to use `__root__` to define a [root level dictionary response](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#custom-root-types):

```
class CardListResponse(BaseModel):
    __root__: Dict[str, Card]


@router.get("/{item_name}", response_model=CardListResponse)
async def search(item_name):
    pass
```

Comment: how should i set the result i get from the dict to the basemodel?

Comment: You don't, you return the dict from your view function and FastAPI marshals it into the response model for you.

Comment: just wondering how can i handle the card_id then?

Comment: The card_id in your example is the key for each row, so that gets returned as you have documented in your example data. This is what the `__root__` value in the `CardListResponse` describes in the model, that there's a string (the card_id) pointing to each card.

Comment: ok thanks alot for explaning, i will try it out in abit

Comment: just one more question, if i also wanted to return a "total_count" of my results from the dict such as total records number, how should i put this into the schema?

Comment: @MatsLindh is there any way to get a custom field in the response model as we do in the serializer field 'get_fiel_name'?

Comment: @user1897151 did you get how to return total_count ?

Comment: @mdhv_kothari Ask a new question with proper details if you have a question.